# Django {% url %} with non Ascii parameters

Tags: python, django, url

I'm using a custom **templatetag**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('parts/sidebar.html', takes_context = True)
def show_sidebar(context):

    districts = models.Apartment.objects.order_by().values_list('district', flat=True).distinct()
    return {
        'districts': districts
        }
```

in the **sidebar.html** it gets the districts and pass them throug a {% url %} tag with district argument to views.district

**sidebar.html**

```
{% load aptAPI_tags %}
<ul>
  {% for district in districts %}
  <li>
       <a href="{% url 'district' district %}">
        {{ district }}
      </a>

  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**views.py**

```
def district(request, district):
try:
    apartments = Apartment.objects.filter(district=district).all()
except Apartment.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("District does not exist")
return render(request, 'district.html', {'apartments': apartments})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^dist=(?P<district>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)', views.district, name='district'),
```

It works just fine with districts as "Eixample" but it doesn't work for districts with non Ascii character as "Horta-Guinardó" or "Sant Andreu" as the string splits on the first non Ascii character and i need them later to filter on the database.
Please any idea? Any help?
Thank you

Comment: The url tag tries to generate valid urls and obviously spaces need to be %20's etc. From what I remember the url tag does this well, so your view needs to adjust this conversion as required, or try passing the data through a post/get request

Comment: thanks, how i process that in the view properly?

Comment: replace %20 in the string with spaces etc, not sure if there is a library that does this for you

Comment: there's no way to get the url back with no %20... etc It also can has accents....

Comment: You don't care about the url, you have a view argument that will have the value

Comment: True, but this view argument comes with special characters formatted to %20, .... I think it has to be a way to decode it to normal string

Comment: Yes, so either string replace them all or see if there is something available that has knowledge of all the different html entities

Comment: it does'nt work, as view argument comes to view already splited before %20.... characters, so i think i should work this inside {% url %} tag

Comment: If its split before the %20 then your url is wrong in your urls.py.

Comment: i've edited my question with the corresponding line of urls.py

Comment: I'm not sure if the rest parameter has an effect since I haven't used rest much but your url needs to at least be matching the kwarg `{% url 'district' district=district %}`

Comment: it doesn't work neither

Comment: @Sayse `{% url %}` accepts positional arguments even when you define named groups in your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex, `[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+`, does not match non-ascii characters. You have to use `\w` instead. The URL dispatcher will set the `re.UNICODE` flag for compiled regexes, and this will match any alphanumerical unicode character.

You'd also want to add `$` to the end of your regex to match the end of line.

```
url(r'^dist=(?P<district>[\w\.%+-]+)/$', views.district, name='district'),
```

Comment: I'm having this error now NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'district' with arguments '(u'Districte 5',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dist=(?P<district>[\\w\\.%+-]+)/$']

Comment: That's because your `district` has a space, but your regex doesn't allow spaces. Either add `\s` to the regex pattern, or better, use a proper slug.

Comment: it now work with spaces but it fails for characters like 'ó', 'à', 'ï'.... as in UnicodeEncodeError at /dist=Sants-Montjuïc/
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That's a new error. Please post a new question with the full traceback.

Comment: isn't it the same error of not accepting not ascii characters in url tag parameters?

Comment: A `UnicodeEncodeError` is a related but different issue.

Comment: it is now everything working fine, thanks for your answer, i'm gonna accept it nowworking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91495/discussion-between-perecullera-and-knbk).